# forming the continued fraction of the euler number

Tags: continued-fractions

Good afternoon

The euler number is a irrational number. And you can have a infinite continued fraction of euler number. But how can you form the coninued fraction of euler number?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e#As_a_continued_fraction

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+of+euler+number

Comment: Well, if you have a decimal expansion out to sufficiently many places, you can at least get the first few partial denominators in the regular continued fraction. One can do that for any real number at all.

Comment: Euler surely deserves a capital letter. Anyway, you may derive the continued fraction of $e$ from the Beuker integrals $\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^m e^{-x}\,dx$ or from the Gauss continued fraction for $\tanh$. Have a look at the last pages of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) for further details.